# Is it possible to create UDF containing dynamic sql execution in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is what I am trying to do, with no luck:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_value_from_json (key string, json string)
AS
(
  (
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format(
  """
  SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.%s')
  """, key
  )
)
);
```

Comment: if you tried above and have no luck - so what is the real question? what is your use case? if you provide more details we might have some workaround for you

Comment: My script didnt work, I want to know if I have some sort of syntax error or is it just not possible in bigquery? In any case i used already a work around for what i needed. I am new to bigquery (i have 8 years experience in sql server) and just want to know if this kind of functionalty possible?

Comment: got it. I don't think scripting is supported within BigQuery UDF, but meantime, I don't remember seeing this explicitly in documentation